# How to hide another html button if login is true?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here are two button tabs :
How to express

1:

`<% if logged_in? %>` then hide b button tag

2:

`<% if studentlogged_in? %>`    then hide A button tag

both methods`<% if logged_in? %> , <% if studentlogged_in? %>` are valid

```
 <% if logged_in? %>  <<==#A button tab
   <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Account <b class="caret"></b>
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li>
         <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 <% else %>
   <li><%= link_to "Tutor Center",  login_path %></li>
 <% end %>



 <% if studentlogged_in? %>  <<==#B button tab
   <li><%= link_to "StudentUsers", student_users_path %></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Account <b class="caret"></b>
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><%= link_to "Profile", studentcurrent_user %></li>
       <li>
         <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(studentcurrent_user) %>
       </li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li>
         <%= link_to "Log out", studentlogout_path, method: "delete" %>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 <% else %>
   <li><%= link_to "Student Center",  studentlogin_path %></li>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean this structure:

```
<% if studentlogged_in? %>
   ...
<% elsif logged_in? %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Where that shows the student one, the regular one, or nothing, but never both.

Comment: one more condition ; BOth button tags exist if no people logged in

Comment: Just move both of those down into a final `else` clause here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<% if logged_in %>
  # render partial containing html code for button A
<% elsif studentlogged_in %>
  # render partial containing html code for button B
<% else %>
  # render both partials
<% end %>
```

Comment: haha yeah. it's not a competition though we're all trying to help